# Вывод знаковых и беззнаковых чисел в printf

Tags: c++, c

Имеется следующий код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const unsigned char c1 = 200;
    const char c2 = -100;
    printf("sizeof(char)==%lu\n", sizeof(char));
    printf("%hhd %hhu\n", c1, c1);
    printf("%hhd %hhu\n", c2, c2);
    return 0;
}
```

Его вывод:

> sizeof(char)==1
>
> 200 200
>
> -100 65436

Два вопроса:

1. Почему `c1` в обоих случаях вывелось как `200`, несмотря на то, что первый раз указывался спецификатор формата `d` (число со знаком)?
2. Почему `c2` во втором случае вывелось как `65436`, ведь это выходит за пределы допустимого диапазона типа `char`, который в данном случае занимает один байт?

P.S. На всякий случай строка идентификации компилятора:

> gcc (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 5.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде всего хотел бы отметить, что показанный вами вывод на консоль не соответствует используемым спецификаторам формата в вызовах `printf`.

Модификатор `hh` означает, что значение будет выводиться как значение объекта типа `char`. А это означает, что вы не можете получить значение `65436`, так как объект типа `char` не может хранить такое значение в одном байте.
Также для спецификатора формата вывода `%hhd` для значения `200` вы не можете получить то же самое значение, так как знаковые значения в объекте `signed char` не могут содержать значение `200`. Это значение превышает максимально допустимое значение, равное 127.

```
200 200 
-100 65436
     ^^^^^
```

Я запустил ваш код на выполнение и получил следующий вывод на консоль

```
sizeof(char)==1
-56 200
-100 156
     ^^^
```

Возможная причина, полученного вами результата состоит в том, что **данные спецификаторы могут не поддерживаться той версией компилятора**, которую вы используете, а потому вывод на консоль может быть неопределенным.

Теперь по поводу полученных мной значений.

Согласно стандарту C и описанию функции `printf` имеем, что

> **hh** Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier
>   applies to a signed char or unsigned char argument (the
>   argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions,
>   but its value shall be converted to signed char or unsigned char
>   before printing); or that a following n conversion specifier applies
>   to a pointer to a signed char argument.

Следовательно, исходя из того, что вы объявили переменную `c1` как

```
const unsigned char c1 = 200;
```

, то при целочисленном продвижении значения этой переменной до типа `int` внутреннее представление значения так и будет соответствовать значению 200.
Поэтому, когда вы его выводите с помощью спецификатора формата `%hhu`, то будет выведено это же значение, то есть `200`
Когда же вы его выводите с помощью спецификатора формата `%hhd`, то его внутреннее представление будет интерпретироваться как значение со знаком, а потому будет выведено `-56`. В сумме, если взять абсолютные значения этих двух чисел, то вы получите `256`

То же самое имеет место для второй знаковой переменной `c2`, только ее значения будут равны, соответственно, `-100` и `156` для `%lld` и `%llu`

Comment: Для полноты картины хотелось бы узнать, какой у Вас компилятор.

Comment: @kff Для ответов на форумах я использую онлайновые компиляторы, в частности, майкрософтовский http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/

Comment: Спасибо. Даже не знал, что есть MSVC online... Полезная штука. Добавил себе в закладки браузера

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, я поторопился с вопросом и это просто баг реализации `printf` в MinGW. Компилятор GCC в Linux и MSVC2015 выдают правильные результаты:

> sizeof(char)==1
>
> -56 200
>
> -100 156

Оставлю вопрос. Может быть, кому-нибудь поможет.

P.S. Строки идентификации правильно работающих компиляторов:

> gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
>
> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x86

**Update**

MinGW не имеет собственного рантайма и использует `msvcrt.dll` от Microsoft. Анализ бинарника показывает, что `printf` экспортируется именно из этой DLL. Похоже, что ошибка именно там.